# Animate Map in R ggplot

Tags: r, gis

I am using R and library gganimate and have a polygon data frame and a point data frame:

This is the polygon data frame (poly):

```
 long    lat order hole  piece    id group T_P_0_14 T_P_15_64 T_P_65mas  P_TOT P_TOT_HOM
   <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <lgl> <fct> <dbl> <fct>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>
1 5.80e5 6.14e6  2883 FALSE 1        10 10.1     25523    122781     38716 187020     83348
2 5.80e5 6.14e6  2883 FALSE 1        10 10.1     25523    122781     38716 187020     83348
3 5.80e5 6.14e6  2883 FALSE 1        10 10.1     25523    122781     38716 187020     83348
4 5.80e5 6.14e6  2883 FALSE 1        10 10.1     25523    122781     38716 187020     83348
5 5.80e5 6.14e6  2883 FALSE 1        10 10.1     25523    122781     38716 187020     83348
6 5.80e5 6.14e6  2883 FALSE 1        10 10.1     25523    122781     38716 187020     83348
7 5.80e5 6.14e6  2883 FALSE 1        10 10.1     25523    122781     38716 187020     83348
8 5.80e5 6.14e6  2884 FALSE 1        10 10.1     25523    122781     38716 187020     83348
9 5.80e5 6.14e6  2884 FALSE 1        10 10.1     25523    122781     38716 187020     83348
```

And this is the point data frame(points):

```
   codigo  anio   month ascensos coords.x1 coords.x2
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1    546  2013     1      489   578024.  6140711.
2    546  2013     2      403   578024.  6140711.
3    546  2013     3      504   578024.  6140711.
4    546  2013     4      556   578024.  6140711.
5    546  2013     5      505   578024.  6140711.
6    546  2013     6      481   578024.  6140711.
7    546  2013     7      477   578024.  6140711.
8    546  2013     8      512   578024.  6140711.
9    546  2013     9      459   578024.  6140711.
```

I am trying to make an animated plot using gganimate, using month as the transition variable because i want to see the evolution of the point values over time in months.  However, the animation shows movement in the points, which is not possible, because they are fixed. Instead, i want to show the change in the color of these points, which depends on variable ascensos.

How can i fix this? any idea?

Thanks so much

```
ggplot() +
 geom_polygon(data = poly %>% mutate(Macrozona=as.factor(id)),
              aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
              colour = "black")+
 geom_point(aes(x=coords.x1, y=coords.x2, color=ascensos), data=points %>% filter(anio==2019), 
               alpha=0.1)+
 scale_color_gradient(low="blue", high="red")+
 labs(subtitle = paste('Month: {frame_time}'))+
 transition_time(month)
```

Comment: I you are looking for animation some javascript might be useful. Consider using [leaflet](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/). Along with some shiny it might do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble you're running into may be the format of your month variable. `transition_time()` requires data to be in a time format, but your dataframe shows that `month` is a `dbl` format.

Try using `transition_states()` instead, as that command can use data more flexibly. `transition_states()` will also keep your polygon layer static, as you desire.

Comment: Glad that was helpful @Augosto. If you think it's worth an upvote, can you please mark the post as such?

Comment: Hi @Ben, I know this is an old answer but could you elaborate on the static polygon layer part?